# how to select data and display it from json array which contains sub arrays?

Tags: php, json, mongodb

This is my json encoded data

```
echo json_encode($something)
```

gave me this from mongodb database

```
[
    {
        "_id":{ "$id":"535f6dc8b8082fd3f80dea0f"},
        "val":"mukund",
        "value":"Lost in the woods"
    }
]
```

i need to get `535f6dc8b8082fd3f80dea0f` , `mukund` and `Lost in the woods` only from that array to variables $id, $name, $Text

please help

Comment: Why are you encoding in PHP to access in PHP? That sound counter-productive

Comment: these values are obtained from mongodb database as part of a select query which includes subdocuments, what ever i tried without json_encode gave me outputs like null, ArrayArray etc. when i gave `echo json_encode($res[rslt]);` gave what i need, my needed data are in those arrays,so now i want to fetch them, also i can also learn how to do json decoding

Comment: I agree with @Sammaye. Your solution with JSON encoding doesn't make any sense. Could you give us some code on how you get to this object? So a step before this? Then we could help you do it the proper way, which is not with JSON and strings, but with PHP objects or arrays.

Comment: where should i post it?

Comment: I think what people are getting at is that `$something` is already a valid PHP structure, so why are you not using that? But I am a little confused as your prior question seemed to be aimed at get getting a response you could pass to output (presumably as JSON), and the ideal way is to remove the coding steps and try to get the "cleanest round trip" from server to eventual client as possible. So  maybe you are not explaining this as clearly as you intend. It is kind of a very short question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `json_decode()`

```
$j = '[{"_id":{"$id":"535f6dc8b8082fd3f80dea0f"},"val":"mukund","value":"Lost in the woods"}]';
$r = json_decode($j);
 echo (string)$r[0]->_id->{'$id'}; //535f6dc8b8082fd3f80dea0f
 echo $r[0]->val; //mukund
 echo $r[0]->value; //Lost in the woods
```

Comment: i did like this no value is displaying on echo!!,
what i did is that

    `$rawdata= json_encode( $res['rslt']);`
     `$data=json_decode($rawdata);`
     `echo $id[0]->_id."ho";`
      `echo $auth[0]->val;`
      `echo $quote[0]->value;`

Comment: try echo $data[0]->_id->{'$id'}."ho";